# Characteristic of an integral domain is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

> Let $D$ be the Integral Domain with characteristic $m>0$. Prove that $m$ is prime.

My Proof:

Since the characteristic of $D$ is $m$, $m\cdot b=0$ for all $b\in D$ and if $n\cdot b=0$ for all $b\in D$, then $m\leq n$.

Assume that $m$ is composite number. Then $m=n_1n_2$ where $n_1,n_2>1$.

Let $a\in D$. Then $m\cdot a=0$ i.e., $n_1(n_2\cdot a)=0$. Take $c=n_2\cdot a$, then $n_1\cdot c=0$. Since $a$ is an arbitrary element of $D$, $c$ is also an arbitrary element of $D$. So, we have $n_1\cdot c=0$ for all $c\in D$ and $m> n_1$. This is a contradiction. So, our assumption that $m$ is composite number,  is false. Hence $m$ is a prime number.

Comment: You'll need to justify that $c$ may represent any old member of $D$.

Comment: Note that the last paragraph of your proof doesn't depend upon the assumption that $n_1>1$. In other words, your proof would also address the factorization $m=1\cdot m$, even when $m$ is prime, thus showing that the only possible finite characteristic is $1$. So there's definitely an error (and DavidP pointed out where it is).

Answer (score 3):

If your definition of integral domain requires an identity, it's easy: the unique ring homomorphism (preserving identities)
$$
\chi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to D
$$
has kernel $m\mathbb{Z}$, so $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to a subring of $D$ and therefore is a domain. Hence either $m=0$ or $m$ is prime.

If $D$ is not required to have an identity, you can still consider the field of quotients $Q$ of $D$, which has the same characteristic as $D$ and so the previous argument works.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify things, let $m$ be the characteristic of $D$. Let $m=nk$ be a factorization of $m$. Then $m\cdot 1=(nk)\cdot 1=(n \cdot 1)(k\cdot 1)=0$. Since $D$ is an integral domain, either $n \cdot 1=0$ or $k \cdot 1=0$. But $m$ is the least integer for which $m \cdot 1=0$, implying $n=1$ or $k=1$, so $m$ is prime.

Answer (score 0):

As an integral domain has no zero divisors, if it has a finite characteristic it is itself finite. So it is a field and contains an unit element, $1$. Let $m=a.b$ if possible, for some integers $a,b>1$. Then $a.1=a\in D$. Let all the elements of $D$ be $x_1,\cdots,x_n$. If $a.x_i=a.x_j$ for $i\neq j$ then as $D$ has no zero divisors $x_i-x_j=0$, contradicting  $i\neq j$. Hence $a.x_1,\cdots,a.x_n$ constitute all elements of $D$. But $b.(a.x_i)=0$ for all $i$. But then $b<m$ satisfies $b.x=0$ for all $x\in D$, contradicting the fact that the characteristic is $m$.